# Intellij Idea Ultimate Postgres/EDB database plugin "oid" is ambigous

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I use Intellij Idea Ultimate 2016.3 version. I try to connect to Postgres DB using the Intellij Idea's default "Database" plugin. However when i try to sync with the DB, I see this in the event log:

> ERROR: column reference "oid" is ambiguous Position: 1205.

I tried checking the logs and this is what I found.

```
Caused by: org.jetbrains.dekaf.exceptions.StrippedSQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column reference "oid" is ambiguous   Position: 1205
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:420)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:413)
at org.jetbrains.dekaf.jdbc.JdbcIntermediateSeance.execute(JdbcIntermediateSeance.java:100)
at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.impl.RemoteSeanceImpl.execute(RemoteSeanceImpl.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
... 3 more
```

Then I see there is a query like below getting executed.

```
The SQL statement:

select max(last_tx) as state_number from (select max(xmin::varchar::bigint) as last_tx
    from pg_catalog.pg_type
    where typnamespace = oid(?)  
union all 
select max(xmin::varchar::bigint) as last_tx 
from pg_catalog.pg_class where relnamespace = oid(?) 
union all 
select max(xmin::varchar::bigint) as last_tx 
from pg_catalog.pg_proc where pronamespace = oid(?) 
union all 
select max(xmin::varchar::bigint) as last_tx 
from pg_catalog.pg_operator where oprnamespace = oid(?) 
union all   
select max(A.xmin::varchar::bigint) as last_tx 
from pg_catalog.pg_attribute A 
join pg_catalog.pg_class K on K.oid = A.attrelid 
where K.relnamespace = oid(?) 
union all 
select max(xmin::varchar::bigint) as last_tx 
from pg_catalog.pg_constraint 
where connamespace = oid(?) 
union all 
select max(IX.xmin::varchar::bigint) as last_tx 
from pg_catalog.pg_index IX,  pg_catalog.pg_class IC 
where IC.oid = IX.indrelid and IC.relnamespace = oid(?) 
union all 
select max(RU.xmin::varchar::bigint) as last_tx 
from pg_catalog.pg_rewrite RU, pg_catalog.pg_class RC 
where RC.oid = RU.ev_class and RC.relnamespace = oid(?)  
union all 
select max(TG.xmin::varchar::bigint) as last_tx 
from pg_catalog.pg_trigger TG,  pg_catalog.pg_class TC 
where TC.oid = TG.tgrelid and TC.relnamespace = oid(?) 
union all 
select max(DE.xmin::varchar::bigint) as last_tx  
from pg_catalog.pg_description DE, pg_catalog.pg_class DC 
where DC.oid = DE.objoid and DC.relnamespace = oid(?) and DC.relkind in ('r', 'm', 'v')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a thorough search on Intellij Idea forums, I did the following:

1. While creating the connection, under "Options" tab, provide a Object filter. Ex: table:ABC_.* (assuming all the tables start with a ABC_ prefix)
2. Check on "Introspect using JDBC metadata"
3. Choose "Except System Schemas" from the select box "Load sources for"

After the above steps, was able to resolve the issue. The below links helped me:

1. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207089995--Basic-attribute-type-should-not-be-Object-
2. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150816
3. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2771

Hope this helps someone